# Forming a pack for structure containing integer array,string list in python

Tags: python, c, python-2.7

In C we have

```
struct temp
{
  unisgned int i[10];
  char a[2][10];
}temp;
```

Like this i am making one structure in python:

```
integer_aray=[1,2,3,4,5]
string_array=["hello","world"]
format_="Qs"
temp = namedtuple("temp","i a")                                      
temp_tuple =  temp(i=integer_array,a=string_array)
string_to_send = struct.pack(format_, *temp_tuple)
```

When i am trying like this python 2.7 giving error

```
string_to_send = struct.pack(format_, *temp_tuple)
error: cannot convert argument to integer
```

I have to send the python structure as and array of integer and as an array of strings.Is there any way we can do by sending arrays without using ctypes ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pack the equivalent of the C struct

```
struct temp
{
  unsigned int i[10];
  char a[2][10];
};
```

you will use the format `"10I10s10s"` where `10I` stands for 10 4-byte unsigned integers in native order, and each `10s` represents a byte string of size 10.

In Python3, you could write:

```
l = list(range(1, 11))            # [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
temp = struct.pack("10I10s10s", *l, b"hello", b"world")
print(temp)
```

it would give (on a little endian ASCII platform):

```
b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\x00hello\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00world\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

which is compatible with the C `temp` struct on a 32 bits little endian system.

Comment: cant we send as list of strings.or any other way using of ctypes modules or any other modules.

Answer (score 0):

`char *a[2][10];` is a 2D array of 2x10 pointers.

You probably meant to do either `char a[2][10];` which is an array of 2 C strings, each 9+1 characters long. Or perhaps `char* a[2]`, which is two pointers to characters (possibly arrays).

Comment: yeah i required char a[2][10]